# How to apply binary mask on text images to separate text regions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, text, mask

I have some scene text images, on which I have to apply a binary mask to get an output image as **text pixels being 1** and **non text pixels being 0** as a preprocessing stage in scene text detection.

How to achieve the same?

I can provide sample images if required.

The sample images are provided here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from PIL import Image

image_original = Image.open('kSZzc.png')
image_gray = image_original.convert("L") # Convert to grayscale image
image_gray_bw = image_gray.point(lambda pixel: 0 if pixel<128 else 255) # convert to binary image
```

If text part of the image has relatively brighter colors, invert the location of 0 and 255 in the code to make the text color black, not white, as in the case for your third image.

Comment: You're right. If that's the case, maybe, you can split the original image into RGB components 'image_original.split()' and manipulate the digital numbers and merge them. Contrast stretching may help. Check this one https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/contrast%20stretching